# liferay. Exсlude default keywords for search

Tags: java, liferay

I use KeywordQueryContributor for search.
The
DefaultKeywordQueryContributor
code automatically adds description, userName, and title fields to the keyword search query.
https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/7-2/user/-/knowledge_base/u/configuring-search#default-keyword-query
I tried to add a model class to the list of ignorings, but it does not help.
How to exclude default keywordsfrom search query?

```
public class AdvertKeywordQueryContributor implements KeywordQueryContributor {
    @Override
    public void contribute(String keywords, BooleanQuery booleanQuery, KeywordQueryContributorHelper keywordQueryContributorHelper) {
        SearchContext searchContext = keywordQueryContributorHelper.getSearchContext();
        queryHelper.addSearchLocalizedTerm(booleanQuery, searchContext, "theme", true);
        queryHelper.addSearchLocalizedTerm(booleanQuery, searchContext, "description", true);
    }

    @Reference
    protected QueryHelper queryHelper;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. please check https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824